# Prevent vim closing the editor when the last window/splits are help pages

Tags: help-system

When I am working in vim, I often have a split, or splits, open containing a help files.
If I close other windows using `:q` such that vim would be left in a state with only help windows open, vim closes the entire editor, which causes me to lose my position in the help pages. e.g. Say I have this layout

```
  tab1 (this is the only tab open)
+------------------+-------------+-----------------+
|                  |             |                 |
|                  |:h usr_26.txt|                 |
|  A normal file,  |             |    :h change.txt|
|  containing code |section 26.2 |                 |
|  e.g.            |line 47      |    line 272     |
|                  |             |                 |
|  app_db.sql      |             |                 |
|                  |             |                 |
|                  |             |                 |
|                  |             |                 |
|                  |             |                 |
|                  |             |                 |
|                  |             |                 |
+------------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

If I were to enter the window containing `app_db.sql` an issue the `:q` command, surprisingly the entire editor would be lost.
It often takes me a long time - up to 15-20mins - of searching the help to finally discover that help content, so even though it's not exactly lost work, it's definitely a lot of time lost when this happens.
How can I prevent vim closing the editor itself when I close a window with only help windows open?

Possible solutions I've considered

- Simply don't close the last window when there are help windows open.

  - the problem with this is I am not paying attention to what's in other  windows when I close the current window.
- Use `mksession`

  - this requires that you know ahead of time that you need to `:mksession` and the editor closing always occurs unexpectedly.
- Use a plugin like [vim obsession](https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession) which constantly update a `Session.vim` file.

  - I've currently paused using vim-obsession because of (ironically), the `Session.vim` files vim obsession makes often don't restore tabs containing help pages, but the `Session.vim` files generated by `:mksession` do restore the tabs with help windows. (Also another issue with tab labels getting mis-matched with the tabs themselves)

Comment: There may be unintended side-effects, but you could try an autocmd watching the `QuitPre` event which would give the focus back to the previous window before closing the current one: `autocmd QuitPre * wincmd p`

Comment: @user9433424 nice, that works! thanks. I'll add to my `~/.vimrc` and keep an eye on any weird side-effects

Comment: @user9433424 actually its not working in all cases, possibly when the last window open is not marked as the previous window, i.e. the `wincmd p` is not working because p is null maybe. I will have to test a bit later when i get time

Comment: Yes you're right sorry, I've just realised it didn't work when there were just 2 windows, and you were closing the help window (then it quits Vim). Maybe someone will have another working solution.

Comment: `obsession` will save help windows if you add `help` to `sessionoptions` some time before saving the session: `set sessionoptions+=help`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura yes I think the problems are caused by the fact I am using [taboo.vim](https://github.com/gcmt/taboo.vim) and Obsession together - I think by themselves they work ok, but together there seems to be some conflict.

Comment: As far as I can tell `taboo` doesn't touch `sessionoptions`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura oh yea taboo touches sessionoptions! well technically  you need to modify sessionoptions yourself to get your taboo tabs restored i.e. `set sessionooptions+=globals,tabpages` they suggest this snippet on the [taboo github readme](https://github.com/gcmt/taboo.vim) this is a bad snippet because it doesnt check what `sessionoptions` value it before it changes it. also tim pope has been [making changes to sessionoptions in obsession](https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession/commit/543286c06727ad8bb9304d3c959877213890ea2d)

Comment: `taboo` __uses__ `sessionoptions`.  It doesn't __change__ it. Have you actually tried my suggestion above before arguing about it?

Comment: @SatoKatsura no point. `help` is already in my `sessionoptions` with or without `:Obsession` . also there are more problems than just missing tabpages with help windows. there are tab labels that are attached to the wrong tabs. I need to spend some time testing

Answer (score 9):

using the command `:clo[se]` instead of `:q` seems to have solved the problem for me.
I.e. if I issue `:clo` with the above window layout, it causes vim to throw

> E444: Cannot close last window.

In fact it seems `:close` was intended for this situation, i.e. to prevent accidental closing of the editor when all you wanted to do was close a window (or tab)

from `:h windows.txt`

```
:clo[se][!]
:{count}clo[se][!]
CTRL-W c                    *CTRL-W_c* *:clo* *:close*
        Without {count}: Close the current window.  If {count} is
        given close the {count} window.

        When the 'hidden' option is set, or when the buffer was
        changed and the [!] is used, the buffer becomes hidden (unless
        there is another window editing it).

        When there is only one window in the current tab page and
        there is another tab page, this closes the current tab page.
        |tab-page|.

        This command fails when:            *E444*
        - There is only one window on the screen.
        - When 'hidden' is not set, [!] is not used, the buffer has
          changes, and there is no other window on this buffer.
        Changes to the buffer are not written and won't get lost, so
```